# SQL monthly join and monthly total percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subtotal

My head is smoking from (stupid) tries of using `JOIN`, `WITH` and `GROUP BY` to come up with a solution for my pretty common scenario - I just can't wrap my head around it. Let me throw the example at you right away:

I have two tables (ColorCount and Colorname):

```
ColorCount:
ColorID Count Date
1       42    2010-09-07
1       1     2010-09-08
2       22    2010-09-14
1       20    2010-10-10
3       4     2010-10-14
```

---

```
ColorName:
ColorID  Name
1        Purple
2        Green
3        Yellow
4        Red
```

---

Now all I want is to join the ColorName table to the ColorCount table, sum up all the counts of colors per month and calculate the percentage of each count from the the monthly total. Tables are better than words:

```
Output:
Month Color   Count Percentage
09    Purple  43    66%
09    Green   22    33%
09    Yellow  0     0%
09    Red     0     0%
10    Purple  20    83%
10    Green   0     0%
10    Yellow  4     16%
10    Red     0     0%
```

*(Please note the total Count of Month `09` is `65`, hence the `66%` for `Purple` and also the `0`'s for non-existing colors):*

I hope somebody dreams in SQL and this is an easy task...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, with the following caveats:

- The datetime values must be date only
- It only lists those months for which there is any data
- I list by first day of the month, in case you have data that crosses years (I'm assuming you don't want to aggregate data from Jan 2009 with data from Jan 2010)
- The precise Percentage column formatting details I leave up to you, I gotta get back to work

Code:

```
;with cte (ColorId, Mth, TotalCount)
 as (select
        ColorId
       ,dateadd(dd, -datepart(dd, Date) + 1, Date) Mth
       ,sum(Count) TotalCount
      from ColorCount
      group by ColorId, dateadd(dd, -datepart(dd, Date) + 1, Date))
 select
    AllMonths.Mth [Month]
   ,cn.Name
   ,isnull(AggData.TotalCount, 0) [Count]
   ,isnull(100 * AggData.TotalCount / sum(AggData.TotalCount * 1.00) over (partition by AllMonths.Mth), 0) Percentage
  from (select distinct Mth from cte) AllMonths
   cross join ColorName cn
   left outer join cte AggData
    on AggData.ColorId = cn.ColorId
     and AggData.Mth = AllMonths.Mth
  order by AllMonths.Mth, cn.ColorId
```

Comment: Good discussion of windowing techniques on SimpleTalk, at http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/working-with-window-functions-in-sql-server/?utm_source=simpletalk&utm_medium=email-main&utm_content=WindowsFunction-20101101&utm_campaign=SQL

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    [Month],
    [Name],
    [Count],
    CASE WHEN TotalMonth=0 THEN 'INF' ELSE cast(round([Count],0)*100.0/TotalMonth,0) as int) + '%' END as [Percentage]
FROM 
(
SELECT 
    [Months].[Month] as [Month],
    CN.[Name],
    isnull(CC.[Count],0) as [Count],
    (SELECT SUM([Count]) FROM ColorCount WHERE 
            datepart(month,[Date])=datepart(month,CC.[Date])
     ) as [TotalMonth]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT datepart(month,[Date]) as [Month] FROM ColorCount) [Months]
LEFT JOIN ColorName CN ON [Months].[Month]=datepart(month,CC.[Date])
LEFT JOIN ColorCount CC ON CN.ColorID=CC.ColorID
) AS tbl1
ORDER BY
    [Month] ASC,
    [Name] ASC
```

Something like that....
It won't display the leading zero of the month, but does it really matter?

Comment: Good try but the percentages are off.

Comment: better but you should convert to float to avoid rounding errors.

Comment: it also may generate a division by zero exception, but to avoid this there's just a LOT of typing involved. i'll try to sort that out. And what about percentages? Why off?

Comment: leading 0 doesn't matter, but your SQL doesn't quite yield the correct result. the output does not contain the empty Colors, but only the overall empty color Red - see generated output here: http://imgur.com/tv0fX.jpg

Comment: Try it now. Though if this doesn't work I'll have to create the tables on my server.

Comment: Sorry, Alexander `The multi-part identifier "CC.Date" could not be bound.`